# Tile rendering/position updating performance

Tags: c++, performance, game, sdl

The code below grabs the contents of a .txt file, and scans each character of it, using that data to create a tile set. My main concern, is that for each loop, I am opening and closing a file each time, and that is obviously performance-intensive. I want to create an array of images, based on the files, but I'm not sure how to implement that. I have tried to comment out the code for you, but the draw_map function is the main problem.

[Here](http://www.pastebin.ca/2910708) is a pastebin link to the contents of Map00.

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

This is made for Linux, but should work on Windows. Compile with the -lSDL and -lSDL_image arguments.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400, BITDEPTH = 32, FRAMES_PER_SECONDS = 90; //Window Constants

//Surfaces to play with
SDL_Surface *tile0 = 0;
SDL_Surface *screen = 0;
SDL_Surface *userTile = 0;


//Used for keyboard input tracking
SDL_Event event;

//Used for changing image from 24-bit to 32-bit Alpha
SDL_Surface *load_image(std::string filename) {
    SDL_Surface *loaded_image = 0;
    SDL_Surface *optimized_image = 0;

    loaded_image = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

    optimized_image = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(loaded_image);
    SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_image);

return optimized_image;

}

//Display image onto surface
void blit_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination) {
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x, offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);

}

//Starts all the processes we need
void initialize() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, BITDEPTH, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("TileSystem", NULL);

}

//Loads the images into memory
void load_files() {
    tile0 = load_image("Grass.png");
    userTile = load_image("userCharacter.png");
}

//Removes the images from memory
void clean_up() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(tile0); SDL_FreeSurface(userTile);

}


class user {
    public:
        int x;//Position on screen where the surface currently is
        int y;
        int offsetX;//Used for adjusting everything else to give the illusion of scrolling
        int offsetY;
        int movSpeed;//How fast the user is allowed to move
        user() {};

        void update(std::string direction) {

                if (direction == "UP") {y -= movSpeed;}
                else if (direction == "DOWN") {y += movSpeed;} // Checks for movement, if so, increases appropriate variable
                else if (direction == "LEFT") {x -= movSpeed;}
                else if (direction == "RIGHT") {x += movSpeed;}
                else {
                    x += 0;
                    y += 0;
                }

                if (y > (SCREEN_HEIGHT - userTile->h) ) {
                    y = (y-movSpeed);
                    offsetY -= movSpeed;
                }
                else if (x > (SCREEN_WIDTH - userTile->w) ) { //Checks to see if the user has exceeded the boundaries of the screen, if so, move the user back based up his speed, and increment the offset appropriately
                    x = (x-movSpeed);
                    offsetX -= movSpeed;
                } 
                else if (x < 0) {
                    x = (x+movSpeed);
                    offsetX += movSpeed;
                }
                else if (y < 0) {
                    y = (y+movSpeed);
                    offsetY += movSpeed;
                }
                else {
                    x += 0, y += 0, offsetX += 0, offsetY += 0;
                }

            blit_surface(x, y, userTile, screen);   //Displays the user image on surface
        }


    user(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->offsetX = 0;//constructor for initialization values
        this->offsetY = 0;
        this->movSpeed = 2;
    }
};

//Loads file into memory, scans through it, displaying the image as it goes
void draw_map(std::ifstream &Map, std::string filename, user User) {
    char charType;
    int tileX = User.offsetX;//Sets initial drawing values to the offset(which will be zero for first draw)
    int tileY = User.offsetY;

    Map.open(filename);//Loads file
    blit_surface(tileX, tileY, tile0, screen);//Displays first tile

    while(Map >> std::noskipws >> charType) {//Changes draw cursor based on height/width
        if (charType == '0') {
            tileX += tile0->w;
        }
        else if (Map.peek() == '\n') {
            tileX = User.offsetX;
            tileY += tile0->h;
        }

    blit_surface(tileX, tileY, tile0, screen);//Displays the rest of the tiles
    }
    Map.close();
}


//Contains functions for keyboard input/game updates
class Display {
    public: 
        void processInput(std::string &direction, bool &game, bool &will_cap) {
            Uint8 *key_held = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);


            if (key_held[SDLK_UP]) {direction = "UP";}//Checks for keyboard presses
            else if (key_held[SDLK_DOWN]) {direction = "DOWN";}
            else if (key_held[SDLK_LEFT]) {direction = "LEFT";}
            else if (key_held[SDLK_RIGHT]) {direction = "RIGHT";}
            else {
                direction = "";
            }   

            while (SDL_PollEvent ( &event )) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                game = false;
                }

            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN) {//Used for turning the FPS cap on & off
                    will_cap  = (!will_cap);
                }
            }


            }
        };

        void updateEverything(std::ifstream &Map, std::string filename, user &User, std::string direction) { //Handles all updates/display flipping

            draw_map(Map, filename, User);

            User.update(direction);

            SDL_Flip(screen);

        }

};

//Used for measuring framerate, but other uses(such as pause, start, stop), are included for further use
class Timer {
    public:
        int startTicks;

        int pausedTicks;

        bool paused;

        bool started;

    public:

    Timer() {
        startTicks = 0;
        pausedTicks = 0;

        paused = false;
        started = false;
    }

    void start() {
        started = true;

        paused = false;

        startTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
    }

    void stop() {
        started = false;

        paused = false;
    }

    int get_ticks() {
        if (started) {
            if (paused) {
                return pausedTicks;
            }
            else {
                return (SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }

    void pause() {
        if ((started) && (!paused)) {
            paused = true;

            pausedTicks = (SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks);
        }
    }

    void unpause() {
        if (paused) {
            paused = false;

            startTicks = (SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks);

            pausedTicks = 0;
        }
    }

    bool is_started() {
        return started;
    }
    bool is_paused() {
        return paused;
    }


};






int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream Map;//File object
    std::string filename = "Map00.txt";
    int charStartX = 300, charStartY = 200; //Character starting position, the rest of the below variables are self-explanatory
    bool game = true;
    std::string direction;
    int frame = 0;//Used for measuring FPS
    bool will_cap = true;
    Timer fps;


    initialize();//Loads SDL and Co. into memory

    user User(charStartX, charStartY); //Creates user object

    Display display; //Creates display object, used for handling keyboard input/display updates

    load_files();//loads the images into memory

    draw_map(Map, filename, User); //Scans file, displaying it onto the screen as it goes


    while (game) { //Main Game Loop

        fps.start(); //Starts fps timer
        display.processInput(direction, game, will_cap);//Checks for keyboard input

        display.updateEverything(Map, filename, User, direction);//updates and displays all images on screen
        frame++;

        if ((will_cap) && (fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECONDS)) { //Makes sure the framerate stays at the prescribed number
            SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECONDS ) - fps.get_ticks());
        }

    }



clean_up(); //Removes all surfaces from memory

}
```

Comment: Do you expect the contents of the file to be different each time you open it in the loop?

Comment: No, it is a constant file. It's like a base world level.

Comment: Do you have any other style/performance/code structure critique?

Comment: Then it should be very easy to update your code to read the contents only once and reuse the data in each loop.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I don't need a special SDL property to hold all the chars...for some reason I wanted to store the images...I don't know what I was thinking. Anyway, are there any other issues that you can find, with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way of reading the contents of the file once and using the contents in the loop.

**Function to read the contents**

```
void getCharList(std::string const& filename,
                 std::vector<char>& charList)
{
   std::ifstream infile(filename);
   char ch;
   while ( infile >> std::noskipws >> ch )
   {
      charList.push_back(ch);
   }
}
```

**Updated `main`**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::string filename = "Map00.txt";
   int charStartX = 300, charStartY = 200; //Character starting position, the rest of the below variables are self-explanatory
   bool game = true;
   std::string direction;
   int frame = 0;//Used for measuring FPS
   bool will_cap = true;
   Timer fps;

   initialize();//Loads SDL and Co. into memory

   user User(charStartX, charStartY); //Creates user object

   Display display; //Creates display object, used for handling keyboard input/display updates

   load_files();//loads the images into memory

   std::vector<char> charList;
   getCharList(filename, charList);

   draw_map(charList, filename, User); //Scans file, displaying it onto the screen as it goes

   while (game) { //Main Game Loop

      fps.start(); //Starts fps timer
      display.processInput(direction, game, will_cap);//Checks for keyboard input

      display.updateEverything(charList, filename, User, direction);//updates and displays all images on screen
      frame++;

      if ((will_cap) && (fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECONDS)) { //Makes sure the framerate stays at the prescribed number
         SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECONDS ) - fps.get_ticks());
      }

   }

   clean_up(); //Removes all surfaces from memory
}
```

**Updated `draw_map`**

```
void draw_map(std::vector<char> const& charList, std::string filename, user User) {
   int tileX = User.offsetX;//Sets initial drawing values to the offset(which will be zero for first draw)
   int tileY = User.offsetY;

   blit_surface(tileX, tileY, tile0, screen);//Displays first tile

   for ( auto ch : charList ) {//Changes draw cursor based on height/width
      if (ch == '0') {
         tileX += tile0->w;
      }
      else if (ch == '\n') {
         tileX = User.offsetX;
         tileY += tile0->h;
      }

      blit_surface(tileX, tileY, tile0, screen);//Displays the rest of the tiles
   }
}
```

**Updated `updateEverything`**

```
  void updateEverything(std::vector<char> const& charList, std::string filename, user &User, std::string direction) { //Handles all updates/display flipping

     draw_map(charList, filename, User);

     User.update(direction);

     SDL_Flip(screen);

  }
```

**Other suggestions**

There is too much codde in one file. In addition to many helper functions, you have the following classes:

1. `user`
2. `Display`
3. `Timer`

For the sake of naming consistency, I would change the class `user` to `User`. I would put the declarations of the classes in three header files - User.h, Display.h, and Timer.h. I would move the implementations to User.cpp, Display.cpp, and Timer.cpp, respectively.

I would put the declarations of all the helper functions in a .h file (call it tileFunctions.h, for example), and put the definitions of the helper functions in a corresponding .cpp file (call it tileFunctions.cpp, for example).

**Reduce objects in global scope**

You have

```
SDL_Event event;
```

which is used only in `Display::processInput`. I would move the global object to an to be local variable in the function scope.

You also have:

```
SDL_Surface *tile0 = 0;
SDL_Surface *screen = 0;
SDL_Surface *userTile = 0;
```

in the global scope. I would create a `struct` that holds these together and pass the `struct` around, starting from `main`. That would remove the need for them to be in global scope.

**Use an `enum` instead of strings for direction**

Instead of using strings "UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", and "RIGHT" for directions, use an `enum`.

```
enum Direction { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to read a file every time you want to display something, that could be *incredibly* slow (assuming the file was of any reasonable size).  You want to read the file once into memory, and draw the map from that.

Build a two dimensional array.  Fill that in a load_map() function with the whole file, then draw the tiles out of that at a given offsets every time you update the screen.

EDIT: in response to comments—

Well, this isn't an SDL issue, it's just a C++ issue.   I'm answering this on my phone, so I can't really write an elaborate answer, but if it were me I'd use a single-dimensional std::vector or alternatively (less efficiently) a two dimensional std::vector< std::vector< int > > where the value in the array(s) is an int that corresponds to the index of tile that you want to draw.  You'll want to encapsulated that into a 'Map' class.  I also assume ultimately, you'll want more than two tiles.

The good thing is there are a million tutorials on tile based games in C++.

As far as other critiques, I wouldn't address the rest, because the performance issue that exists is so fundamental that any other issues pale in comparison.

Comment: Yea, I know that. I'm saying I don't know how to implement that in SDL. And are there any other performance issues with the code?

Comment: I'm going for a full review of the code in it's current form: structure, design, clarity, etc

Comment: This answered my question, I read it wrong. Thank you.  Are there any other style structure critiques that you can come up with? Thank you

Comment: I'll edit a bit more